# How to add unknown amount of header parameters to http request?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

I want  to make a http request. I am using the JAX-RS jersey client api. Here is my code:

```
public RestResponse restPost(String sessionMap, String requestURL, String jsonRequest, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers) { 

    String baseURL = session.get("baseurl");
    System.out.println("baseURL: " + baseURL);

    WebTarget target = getWebTarget().path(requestURL);

    Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                              .headers(headers) **//past in a multi value map ex: ["ContentType":"application/json", "Content-Length":"158"]**
                              .post(Entity.json(jsonRequest));

    int responseCode = response.getStatus();
    String responseData = response.readEntity(String.class);
    String contentType = response.getHeaderString("Content-Type");
    RestResponse data = new RestResponse(responseCode, responseData);

    System.out.println("response code: " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("response Data: \n" + responseData);
    System.out.println("content-type: " +  contentType);

    //parseJSON(responseData);

    return data;
}
```

I want the user to be able to past in any number of header parameter through some kind of map. I saw that is a .headers() method that takes in a multivaluemap but I cannot instantiate that because it's an interface. Is there a work around? How else can I allow user to past in a map of headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MultivaluedHashMap` which implements `MultivaluedMap` interface.